# Why would Keepass2 decrease the password quality after adding another character?

Tags: password-management

In Keepass2 I was typing in a password and noticed the number of bits went down. Why would this be? I was using two words and mixed them up by replacing certain letters with numbers.

Comment: "the number of bits went down" -- bits of what? Could you elaborate?

Comment: @DitmarWendt I don't know. While you type in your password there's a field labeled "quality" and it has a progress bar and beside it it has an integer that usually grows larger as you type in more characters but this time it went down. I assumed it was an entropy measurement but how could entropy go down?

Answer (score 9):

I haven't reviewed keepass2 source code, but entropy calculations are very dependent on the model used.  My guess is your change, causes keepass2 to jump between different models for how its doing the underlying calculation.  Any entropy calculation for a given password is necessarily inexact if the method that generated the password is not being used.

For example a very naive way to model a given password like `P@s$w0rd` would be assumed to be assume this was 8 random characters chosen with from a set 96 possible printable ASCII characters, with an entropy of lg(96^8) ~ 52.7 bits -- a somewhat reasonable password (against online attacks or against a hash like bcrypt with suitable number of rounds).  Randomly choosing 8 characters from printable ASCII is as likely to produce `P@s$w0rd` as any other password (even ones that look random `9MD10]'e`)..

However, you can really see that there's an lower-entropy way to generate this password.  It's based off a very common base word (`password`) -- slightly modified with on average maybe four ~4 possible mutations (4 = 2^2 so 2 bits) for each letter.  So by being one of the say 1000 most popular base-words (10-bits of entropy) plus 2 bits for each letter, so a total of about 26 bits of entropy -- which is very weak.

Therefore, some password calculators will search for recognizable patterns to discount for this effect.  They may recognize a pattern in a longer password or a password with a larger character set, that they did not recognize earlier.  E.g., they may not realize that `d@s$w0rd` is based off of password (with a repeating `d` being a rotated `p` and not using any capital letters) and may give it a higher score than `P@s$w0rd`.

Comment: It sounds to me like this is what happened though I'm surprised; I used two words and I wouldn't think the base dictionary is big enough. For example `ye11owsh!rt`

Comment: To see what Jim meant, ask yourself how many bits of entropy do these passwords have:
`yellowsh¡rt`, 
`yellowsh!rt`,
`yellowshïrt` with the hypothesis the attack robot will have the words `yellow` & `shirt` within its dictionary.

Answer (score 1):

The entropy of a password doesn't increase proportionally to its length.

The entropy may decrease because pattern regularity of the password increases or because the password is approaching a dictionary attack vulnerable point.

Here is the result of a blind test with the Google password strength estimate.
The tested password entropy is decreasing with length because approaching a dictionary weakness point[image: password = yellow][image: password = yellowsh][image].